# State symbol for electron

Tags: electrons, phase, notation

Is it correct to write a state symbol of "g" or "l" for an electron? In the textbook I am currently reading, the state symbol "g" was used for the electron when it described the electron gain by a proton in the gas phase. However, I recall that my chemistry teacher mentioned that electrons should not be given any state symbols, which I agree with. Just like how we do not assign a a physical state to an atom. E.g. We do not say an atom of gold is in the liquid state. I would like to know what is the purpose of assigning state symbols to electrons, if there is one? And would that be chemically accurate?

Comment: Maybe related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/297/40029

Comment: I guess a state symbol is only necessary if the electron is in a special state such as solvated when $e^-_{solv}, \; e^-_{aq}$ or something similar would be used.  With atoms no state symbol is expected if in their normal state  but if gold were in its liquid or vapour state then $\ce{Au_{(l)} ,  Au_{(g)}}$  respectively would be advisable. (btw. electrons are just as much 'physical matter' as protons or atoms are.)

Comment: @porphyrin All right. I will edit my post.

Comment: no need your question is ok :)